# IBM Social Business SmartCloud OAuth 2.0 POSTing new events

Tags: ibm-connections

I am trying to post an event to my IBM Social Business SmartCloud account. I have been able to grant access to the application and get the access and refresh tokens. but when posting the new even I get a 401 error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
    function postEvent(){
    var postString = '{'+
    '"actor": {'+
      '"id": "@me"'+
    '},'+
    '"verb": "post",'+
    '"title": "${share}",'+
    '"content":"This event is my <b>first content</b>",'+
    '"updated": "2012-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",'+
    '"object": {'+
      '"summary": "My Summary",'+
      '"objectType": "note",'+
      '"id": "someid",'+
      '"displayName": "My displayName",'+
      '"url": "mydomain.com"'+
    '}}';
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://apps.na.collabserv.com/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all?format=json&access_token=<access_token>',
      data: postString,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json', 
      headers: {
              // Set any custom headers here.
              // If you set any non-simple headers, your server must include these
              // headers in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header.
              'Content-Type: application/json',
              'Origin': 'https://mydomain.com/',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' :'*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          }
      }).done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      });
}
```

so this is the proxy method using file_get_contents I used to get it working in php, cURL did not work.

`$post = file_get_contents('https://apps.na.collabserv.com/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all?format=json',FALSE,stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'           => 'POST',
        'header'           => "Authorization: Bearer $access_token\r\n".
                              "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
                              "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
        'content'          => $json_data,
    ),
)));`

now the issues is other people can not see my posting even though we're following each other.

got the json structure for embedding a webpage with og tags for a video into my ibm sb activity stream. so the video opens directly in my stream with a thumbnail without linking out in a new window

```
    $json_data = '{"content":"https://mydomain.com/somevideo/",
    "attachments":[{"objectType":"link",
        "displayName":"My Display Name",
        "url":"https://mydomain.com/somevideo/",
        "summary":"My summary",
        "image":{
            "url":"{thumbnail}/api/imageProxy?url=http%3a%2f%2fmydomain.com%2fsomevideo%2fthumbnail.jpg",
                "alt":"My Display Name"
            },
        "connections":{
            "video":{
                "connections":{"mime-type":"application/x-shockwave-flash"},
            "width":"853",
            "height":"480",
            "url":"https://mydomain.com/somevideo/"
            }
        }
    }
    ]
    }';
```

and you post to this url:
https://apps.na.collabserv.com/connections/opensocial/rest/ublog/@me/@all?format=json

Comment: we do not enable CORS requests to our backend services.  what you can look at is adding a second header to your request which is Authorization: Basic <BasicAuth> or Authorization: Bearer <BearerToken>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your code is hosted on a different domain than apps.na.collabserv.com you won't be able to access the REST API with JavaScript alone

In this situation, it is the browser [blocking you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The cross origin header won't work, because the backend is not configured to [enable CORS requests](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled).

You can work around this by accessing the REST API trough an [ajax proxy](https://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html), deployed on the same domain as your page

Comment: thanks guys seems to be I cannot use cURL in PHP I had to use file_get_contents method which is strange.

Comment: you may want to look at the https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/wiki/Introducing-the-SBT-PHP-Core  which describes in more detail PHP implementations